# AWS AnonymousAWSCredentials do not support this operation

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to connect to an Amazon S3 bucket and list the contents, but when I call the ListBucketsAsync method, I'm getting the message "AWS AnonymousAWSCredentials do not support this operation". I'm confused, because I've authenticated the user successfully.

```
  public static async void GetS3BucketsAsync()
    {
        var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(), RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
        CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolID, clientID, provider);
        CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(user1.Username, clientID, userPool, provider);

        string password = user1.Password;

        AuthFlowResponse context = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
        {
            Password = password
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);


        CognitoAWSCredentials credentials =
        user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials(identityPoolID, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);

        using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2))
        {
            ListBucketsResponse response =
                await client.ListBucketsAsync(new ListBucketsRequest()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            foreach (S3Bucket bucket in response.Buckets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bucket.BucketName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `AnonymousAWSCredentials`? What is actually the thing that's authenticated here? Are you running this on EC2? Are you expecting it to pick it up from your profile? As it is, you're telling it to be anonymous and I think what you want is nothing specified (so the default credential chain is used).

Comment: Hi, that's the point - I don't want to use anonymous credentials, I've now changed it to Basic Auth, but my problem still exists: At the moment, I can access resources (S3 bucket, DynamoDB) using my IAM user, but what I need to do is access them using a user pool user. I've been unable to find a decent example that shows this.

Comment: I have the same issue - this is more or less straight from an AWS example!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
credentials = user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials(identityPoolId, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.XXXX);

                string provider = "cognito-idp.ap-XXXX-X.amazonaws.com/" + poolId;
               
                credentials.AddLogin(provider, mfaResponse.AuthenticationResult.IdToken);
```

Comment: thanks - AddLogin was the key piece of info that seemed to be missing from every example I could find!

Comment: I just tried the same thing (from the example at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/cognito-authentication-extension.html). Invoking AddLogin actually caused the process to FAIL with the error given by the OP. The code provided in the example worked.
- C# .NET Framework 4.5 Version 3.7.520.0
- Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication Version 2.4.0 (which is for .NET Standard 2.0)

Answer (score 1):

While previous answers are perfectly valid, I had a different, very frustrating, and time-consuming scenario where this started happening, so in the hope of saving someone else's time, here goes.

My Cognito setup was working correctly until something changed. I started getting the message mentioned in the title. But for me, the reason was a change in the **identity provider attributes for access control**. I started copying some of the Cognito users' attributes to the **claims** in the tokens using the custom mappings on the identity provider aws console page. The problem was some of the claims had a colon in the name. Even further, not all colons were creating this issue. Some were perfectly acceptable by the Identity Provider, but one, in particular, wasn't. The problematic claim name in question is `custom:allowedOrgIds`, I have no idea why.

Anyways, long story short, when using custom mapping of attributes for access control, try not to use special characters when naming the claims to avoid losing a day debugging.